# Fetching data from two related tables via Pointer column

Tags: objective-c, pointers, parse-platform

After reading parse.com documentation and quite a few topics on SO I'm still not closer to the solution which I'm sure is simple...

I'm having default `_User` class with some custom data (first name, etc.) and custom table `Posts` with a column `author` (of type Pointer) that points to `_User` class. In my app I need to list **latest** posts along with author's first name. Is there a simple way how to extract all the data ideally in one query to save requests.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the latest by using orderByDescending on the createdAt property, and get the firstName of the author by including the author in the query:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];

[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

[query includeKey:@"author"];

NSArray * array = [query findObjects];

for(PFObject * object in array)
{
    PFObject * author = [object valueForKey:@"author"];
    NSString * firstName = [author valueForKey:@"firstName"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you cncool, this works for me.  I was trying `[query includeKey:@"_User.firstName"];` to pull only data that I need and not the whole `_User` object. Is there some way how to specify only certain columns I can pull from related `_User` class?

Comment: You can use the method selectKeys: on PFQuery. There is no docs on this yet for some reason though. https://parse.com/questions/retrieving-only-certain-attributes-of-a-pfobject

Comment: Great, it looks it doesn't work on related classes yet, will keep an eye on Parse updates. Thank you cncool for your help!